# Locking in MCS Algorithm

Tags: parallel-processing, synchronization, linux-kernel, spinlock, smp

I would like to implement queued locking in C++ for one of my applications. 
I was going through the algorithm from the following paper :
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.rice.edu%2F~johnmc%2Fpapers%2Ftocs91.pdf&ei=HpRfUKCZFsfWrQfpgIGACQ&usg=AFQjCNF_QamPWhJrq5dSjJjFjO7W3WzJ5Q&sig2=3TU1vo_aAYbM2fmLxeiZ0A

```
type qnode = record
next : ^qnode
locked : Boolean

type lock = ^qnode

// parameter I, below, points to a qnode record allocated
// (in an enclosing scope) in shared memory locally-accessible
// to the invoking processor

procedure acquire_lock (L : ^lock, I : ^qnode)
  I->next := nil
  predecessor : ^qnode := fetch_and_store (L, I)
  if predecessor != nil  // queue was non-empty
    I->locked := true
    predecessor->next := I ---A
    repeat while I->locked   // spin ---C

procedure release_lock (L : ^lock, I: ^qnode)
 if I->next = nil  // no known successor
   if compare_and_swap (L, I, nil)  // compare_and_swap returns true iff it swapped
     return

   repeat while I->next = nil // spin --B
 I->next->locked := false ---D
```

A & B are accessing the same variable( predecessor->next & I->next ) and also C & D( locked variable ) but they are not being locked before accessing. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that these concurrent accesses can race, but the algorithm is designed to be tolerant of that.

The spinning at B is actually to prevent a race with A. At D, we need `I->next` to be non-nil. `I->next` (known as `predecessor->next` here) is set to non-nil by A. As you noticed, this could race, so there is a spinning loop at B to wait for the other thread to set `I->next` to something valid.

Let's look at C & D. The `repeat while I->locked` line is the actual "spinning" part of the lock; if a thread trying to acquire the lock has to wait for another thread to release it, it spins in this loop. If the thread releasing the lock sets `I->next->locked` to `false` before the acquiring thread reaches `repeat while I->locked`, the loop will simply never start.